# Batch command /wait not waiting

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying my hand at some light programming, but have hit a wall I'm hoping someone can help me with.  I'm using an HTPC and a front end media center called Kodi.  Within Kodi I have a program called advanced launcher.  As my MC Kodi is scripted to always be on top, I've been using a batch file for each PC game and program I'm trying to run. It shuts down Kodi, launches the program, and when the program is closed, relaunches Kodi.  This works fine for most programs, but if it has a launcher attached (the example I have is for Dragon Age: Inquisition and the launcher it has Origin) it will run straight through the entire batch file without waiting as I thought I had instructed it.  This only seems to happen in programs that have launchers.  As I'm just starting out, while lines to change or add would be great to get this working, I'd also like to know the reason behind the changes.

```
pskill Kodi.exe

cd /d "I:\Games\Dragon Age Inquisition\"
start /max /wait Dragon Age Inquisition.exe

ping 192.168.1.46 -n 1 -w 15000 > nul

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\"
start /max Kodi.exe
```

Ps Commands were recommended by a friend, not sure if this is also an issue, just seems odd that any program without a launcher works fine, but with a launcher just doesn't seem to function correctly.  Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: The launcher program name has spaces in it. Try: `start /max /wait "" "Dragon Age Inquisition.exe"`. The first set of quotes is because the `start` command parses the first quoted item (if any) as a window name.  Also keep in mind that a launcher program might launch the real program then quit, in which case you may need to come up with some other way to pause/unpause the script.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I tried several variations of the suggestions posted here and still having the same problem.  From some research and looking at them, most of the programs with launchers operate like steam in the sense of calling the application as a child process by an id number, rather than exe.  I think for any of these programs a simple batch file (which is pretty much the limit of my programming abilities) isn't going to do it.  I'll probably work on some different solution.  Thank you so much for the time and effort.  Might not have fixed it, but I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
start  "" /max /wait Dragon Age Inquisition.exe
```

and

```
start "" /max Kodi.exe
```

First argument is always the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
Taskkill /im Kodi.exe
"I:\Games\Dragon Age Inquisition\Dragon Age Inquisition.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\Kodi.exe"
```

Should work how you expect.

Taskkill is the correct command. Use it with /f to force closing.